# http://www.sql-ex.ru exercise #39 returns right result but there is a mistake in the query

Tags: mysql

were is the mistake in my solution?

THE TASK IS
Define the ships that "survived for future battles"; being damaged in one battle, they took part in another.

DESCRIPTION OF DB
The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database has the following relations: 
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement) 
Ships(name, class, launched) 
Battles(name, date) 
Outcomes(ship, battle, result) 
Ships in classes are arranged to a single project. A class is normally assigned the name of the first ship in the class under consideration (head ship); otherwise, the class name does not coincide with any ship name in the database. 
The Classes relation includes the class name, type (bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country where the ship was built, number of main guns, gun caliber (diameter of the gun barrel, in inches), and displacement (weight in tons). The Ships relation includes the ship name, its class name, and launch year. The Battles relation covers the name and date of a battle the ships participated; while the result of their participation in the battle (sunk, damaged, or unharmed - OK) is in the Outcomes relation. 
Notes: 1) Outcomes relation may include the ships not included in the Ships relation. 2) Sunk ship can not participate in battles after that.

MY SOLUTION:

```
select a.ship from
(Select distinct ship, date
from outcomes join battles on outcomes.battle=battles.name
where result = 'damaged') a
join
(Select distinct ship, date
from outcomes join battles on outcomes.battle=battles.name
where result != 'damaged') b 
on a.ship = b.ship
where a.date < b.date
```

RESULT: 
Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
* Wrong number of records (less by 2)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
select distinct kk.ship from
(Select ship,date from outcomes oo,battles bb where oo.battle=bb.name) tt 
inner join 
(Select ship,date as damagedate from outcomes oo,battles bb where result='damaged' AND oo.battle=bb.name) kk 
ON tt.ship=kk.ship AND tt.date>kk.damagedate
```